# Remote application contents shows up small on Surface 3 with Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, outlook, windows-10

One of our clients has a setup with Windows Server 2008 R2 running as an App server, through which we have created several individual .RDP files that we individually move onto computers per their need when they are set up.

The issue I'm running into is with a Surface 3, basically when using the .RDP files to connect to Outlook 2010, Excel 2010, or any other remote apps, the text in the application is outrageously hard to read (like 6-point font looking). When I use the remote desktop connection app to remote into the actual server, it shows up fine, but the ones that link to the applications themselves have very small text/ribbon at the top.

I was wondering if anyone else has run into this issue, and how they fixed it. Changing the Windows 10 "Zoom" settings doesn't seem to have any effect on the way the remote applications look, and the sizing slider in the remote app setup doesn't do anything either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to open the RDP session in a smaller resolution, like 1366x768, and then use the "Smart Sizing" option on the RDP client. Then you will be able to resize the window and get it bigger.

Pascal